# How to replace each array element by 4 copies in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I use numpy / python array routines to do this ?

E.g. If I have array `[ [1,2,3,4,]]` , the output should be

```
[[1,1,2,2,],
 [1,1,2,2,],
 [3,3,4,4,],
 [3,3,4,4]]
```

Thus, the output is array of double the row and column dimensions. And each element from original array is repeated three times.

What I have so far is this

```
def operation(mat,step=2):
    result = np.array(mat,copy=True)
    result[::2,::2] = mat
    return result
```

This gives me array

```
[[ 98.+0.j   0.+0.j  40.+0.j   0.+0.j]
 [  0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j]
 [ 29.+0.j   0.+0.j  54.+0.j   0.+0.j]
 [  0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j]]
```

for the input

```
[[98 40]
 [29 54]]
```

The array will always be of even dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.repeat()`:

```
In [9]: A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [10]: np.repeat(np.repeat(A, 2).reshape(2, 4), 2, 0)
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

***Explanation:***

First off you can repeat the arrya items:

```
  In [30]: np.repeat(A, 3)
  Out[30]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

then all you need is reshaping the result (based on your expected result this can be different):

```
  In [32]: np.repeat(A, 3).reshape(2, 3*2)
  array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

And now you should repeat the result along the the first axis:

```
  In [34]: np.repeat(np.repeat(A, 3).reshape(2, 3*2), 3, 0)
  Out[34]: 
  array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
         [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
         [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
         [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
         [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: Can you add some comments regarding the parameters itself ? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be with [`np.kron`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) -

```
np.kron(a.reshape(-1,2),np.ones((2,2),dtype=int))
```

Basically, we reshape input array into a `2D` array keeping the second axis of `length=2`. Then `np.kron` essentially replicates the elements along both rows and columns for a length of `2` each with that array : `np.ones((2,2),dtype=int)`.

Sample run -

```
In [45]: a
Out[45]: array([7, 5, 4, 2, 8, 6])

In [46]: np.kron(a.reshape(-1,2),np.ones((2,2),dtype=int))
Out[46]: 
array([[7, 7, 5, 5],
       [7, 7, 5, 5],
       [4, 4, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 2, 2],
       [8, 8, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 6, 6]])
```

If you would like to have `4` rows, use `a.reshape(2,-1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use numpy but you could use iteration also:

```python
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

v = iter(a[0])

b = []
for i in v:
    n = next(v)
    [b.append([i for k in range(2)] + [n for k in range(2)]) for j in range(2)]

print b

>>> [[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4, 4]]
```